# Express term from an equation when it is within a sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation like this:

$$\sum (a_i - b)(c - d) = 5$$,

where $b$, $c$ and $d$ are constants, and $a_i$ is a vector of values.

From this equation, how can I express the term $d$?

$$d = ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\sum (a_i - b)(c - d) = 5$$

If you sum is respect to $i$, then $c-d$ is just a constant factor and you can take it out of the sum, which is,

$$(c - d)\sum (a_i - b) = 5$$

then you can solve for $d$, assuming $\sum (a_i - b)\ne 0$

$$d =c-\frac{5}{\sum (a_i - b)}$$